# Correct Terminology for "Smallest" Number which could be Negative

Tags: terminology, roots

I'm writing a paper and I'm doubting myself with a piece of terminology.

I am finding roots of an equation, say {x1, x2}, where it's ambiguous which is greatest from the parameters involved. So possibly x1>x2 or x2>x1.

**What is the correct term for the one of these which is the closest to $-\infty$?**

I'm tempted to use the word "small", but to me that suggests closest to $0$. I also can't use "most negative" as there's a chance they're both positive.

Suggestions appreciated

Comment: "**Smallest**". Why wouldn't it work for negatives?

Comment: @Berci Because "small" can have connotations with close to zero. For instance 0.001 is small, and -100 is "larger" in scale, but it is large and negative. If small is agreeable then I'll feel assured, just got me wondering if there was a definitive answer

Comment: What about "lesser"?

Comment: Or perhaps "**least**" / "**less**".

Comment: Yes, I think that works better, was on the tip of my tongue, thanks :)

Comment: **Minimum** might be a better option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Berci says, *least* would likely be a good option here. It carries neither the "closest to zero" connotation that small does, nor the "very positive" connotation that large does.

Edit:

@Logophobic's suggestion of "minimum" is also relevant, and between the two I think completely answers the question.